# map didn't show in angular google maps library

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developping a phoneGap application with ionic framework and angularjs, i would like to show a map with 2 markers and a route between them, i tried google maps api v3, but i get problems when zooming in the map; the path disappear, so i tested to work with [angular google maps library](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) which is based in google maps api v3, but i didn't found how to draw a path between 2 points;

I would like also to know if this plugin have also problems when zooming in android apps, and if so, i ask if there's a solution with google maps zooming in phonegap apps, i tried also this cordova plugin [google maps cordova plugin](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin), but it has problems with ionic as said its developper.

I tried this code,

```
//this two lines below are responsible for the bug
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"),
       mapOptions);

 directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
   directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var request = {
  origin: start,
  destination:  end,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
 };
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

}    
});
```

i get this errors

```
 Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'uiGmapGoogleMap', required by directive 'uiGmapWindow', can't be found!
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$compile/ctreq?p0=uiGmapGoogleMap&p1=uiGmapWindow     at  file:///C:/cordovaprojets/guide_toulouse/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:76 49:12
 at getControllers  (file:///C:/cordovaprojets/guide_toulouse/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14007:19)
 at file:///C:/cordovaprojets/guide_toulouse/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14015:24
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (file:///C:/cordovaprojets/guide_toulouse/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:7891:11)
at getControllers (file:///C:/cordovaprojets/guide_toulouse/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14014:11)
at nodeLinkFn (file:///C:/cordovaprojets/guide_toulouse/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14179:35)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///C:/cordovaprojets/guide_toulouse/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13578:15)
at publicLinkFn (file:///C:/cordovaprojets/guide_toulouse/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13487:30)
at boundTranscludeFn (file:///C:/cordovaprojets/guide_toulouse/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13601:21) <span class="angular-google-maps-window" ng-transclude="" coords="map.infoWindowWithCustomClass.coords" isiconvisibleonclick="false" options="map.infoWindowWithCustomClass.options">
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: phonegap-googlemaps-plugin works with ionic framework (I'm not familiar with though). Read http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-google-maps-cordova-plugin/4456

Comment: Your plugin is great, i will return to it as the last solution

Comment: Your plugin doesn't allow to trace a route?